# How to retrieve asset in Gatsby Source Contentful? (not images)

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-source-contentful

I'm trying to build a website with Gatsby using with a Contentful CMS source. So far, I've built pages, used images and everything has been quite clear. But now, I'm trying to use an asset linked into one of my content types but I can't find an URL to download it or another way to use it. The asset I'm talking about is a GPX files, not an image. While Gatsby documentation about images is exhaustive, there's little said about other type of files.

My goal is to get the GPX file in one of my React component, parse it and display it on a map. But first I need to download it. So here's my question, how do I do that with Gatsby?

I checked the GraphiQL, but not a single property returns an actually working URL.

[image: Screenshot of the GraphiQL sub-fields of the field linking to my asset]

The `url` field selected in the screenshot returns a broken url (not-https).

### Update - Setting `downloadLocal` to `true`

I set `downloadLocal` to true, ran `gatsby build` and then ran `gatsby develop`. But when I run the query in graphiQL I still receive the same url.

```
{
    "gpxPath": {
        "file": {
          "url": "//assets.ctfassets.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx/59R3KRl13Ppvwh2EGDspjh/41274fe0385d640faa4a092ef3a94804/Lac_de_la_Sassi_re.gpx"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The url is not broken, it's just agnostic of http/https - I can use that URL to download the Lac de la Sassière file which it is linked to. I think your issue may be in the "parsing" of the file for the component. Unless you can pass the raw data held on the remote URL into a component (in the same way you can use a remote image url in an <img/> component)..
You may want to do some work in the gatsby-node.js file, to actually download the file at this point, and store the data within it against a node.

Comment: Indeed! I didn't even realize just adding *https:* made the url work! Currently we're passing the url down the props into a component. is there something wrong with this way of doing things? (You said I may want to do it in gatsby-node.js, but why in particular?). Regardless, thank you for your advice 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried enabling the option [`downloadLocal`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#download-assets-for-static-distribution) configuration option?

This will download the asset locally and should provide a valid URL for static distribution.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
  options: {
    spaceId: `your_space_id`,
    accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    downloadLocal: true,
  },
},
```

As long as your site is deployed to an HTTPS URL it should be a valid route.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I've updated the post with details on how it went implementing this solution. When you say it should be developed to a valid https url, do you mean this is not testable in development?

Comment: it should be testable as well in localhost, it's a local asset. Try cleaning the cache by running `gatsby clean`. Try checking also if there's a new node created like `localUrl` `localAsset` or similar

Comment: Thank you for the additional details! I made it work thanks to your advice. I've found an URL in `localFile { absolutePath }`. 